# Java API for connecting to SAS

Tags: sas

is there a Java API I can use to connect to a SAS metdata server so i can dynamically create information maps through Java? basically, I want to be able to execute "proc infomap" blocks through Java code, is this possible?

THanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run "proc infomap" (or any other arbitrary sas code) from java if that is what you need to do. There are 2 ways to do this either by connecting to a workspace server or to a sas connect spawner. For lots more info on this have a look at this documentation

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/itechjcdg/61499/PDF/default/itechjcdg.pdf

You can also connect directly to the metadata sever from java but I don't know if there is a public api to create info maps.